# error in code for making radio input change image of product with selected color javascript html css

Tags: javascript, html, css

i am having a problem with my code. i am trying to make that when a radio input is selected, the product image changes (the radio inputs are the different colors) but i cant get it to work, i am giving the image 1 (the hoodie) an active class and the second image a imgsec class, as you see the active class has an opacity of 100% and the imgsec has no display, using javascript i check the values of the radio inputs and change switch the classes accordingly, thanks for the help!

```js
if (document.getElementById('black').checked) {
  color_value = document.getElementById('black').value;

  document.getElementById("black").classList.add('active');

  document.getElementById("white").classList.remove('active');

  document.getElementById("white").classList.add('imgsec');

  document.getElementById("black").classList.remove('imgsec');

}


if (document.getElementById('white').checked) {
  color_value = document.getElementById('white').value;

  document.getElementById("black").classList.add('imgsec');

  document.getElementById("white").classList.remove('imgsec');

  document.getElementById("white").classList.add('active');

  document.getElementById("black").classList.remove('active');

}
```

```css
.left-column img.active {
  opacity: 1;
}

.left-colum img.imgsec {
  display: none
}
```

```html
<div class="color-choose">
  <div>
    <!--<input data-image="red" type="radio" id="red" name="color" value="red" checked>
                <label for="red"><span></span></label> -->
  </div>
  <div>
    <input data-image="white" type="radio" id="white" name="color" value="white" class="white">
    <label for="white"><span></span></label>
  </div>
  <div>
    <input data-image="black" type="radio" id="black" name="color" value="black" class="black">
    <label for="black"><span></span></label>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are changing the classes of to the checkbox elements, not to the image elements!
this css refers to img
    .left-column img.active

but this refers to the checkbox
    document.getElementById("white").classList.add('active');

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
$("#black,#white").click(function() {
 if (document.getElementById('black').checked) {
  color_value = document.getElementById('black').value;
  document.getElementById("black-img").classList.add('active');
  document.getElementById("white-img").classList.remove('active');
  document.getElementById("white-img").classList.add('imgsec');
  document.getElementById("black-img").classList.remove('imgsec');
}

if (document.getElementById('white').checked) {
  color_value = document.getElementById('white').value;
  document.getElementById("black-img").classList.add('imgsec');
  document.getElementById("white-img").classList.remove('imgsec');
  document.getElementById("white-img").classList.add('active');
  document.getElementById("black-img").classList.remove('active');
} 

});
});
```

```css
.left-column img.active {
  opacity: 1;
}

.left-column img.imgsec {
    display: none
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="color-choose">
          <div>
            <!--<input data-image="red" type="radio" id="red" name="color" value="red" checked>
            <label for="red"><span></span></label> -->
          </div>
          <div>
            <input data-image="white" type="radio" id="white" name="color" value="white" class="white">
            <label for="white"><span>WHITE</span></label>
          </div>
          <div>
            <input data-image="black" type="radio" id="black" name="color" value="black" class="black">
            <label for="black"><span>BLACK</span></label>
          </div>
        </div>
        
<div class="left-column">
<img id='white-img' class='imgsec' src='data:image/webp;base64,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' />
<img id='black-img' class='imgsec' src='data:image/webp;base64,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' />




</div>
```

Comment: Oh yeah, lol thanks! is there any way you could maybe change the code for me please? i am not very good with code, ive started maybe a month ago haha

Comment: run the code snippet in the answer. There was also a typo in the css. You wrote colum instead of column